# No forward declarations for constexpr - what is the reason?

Tags: c++, global-variables

In [this chapter](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/external-linkage/) from learncpp.com I've found out that `constexpr` variables cannot not be forward declared (and so there is no point in giving their identifier external linkage with the `extern` keyword). I can't understand why a constant variable cannot be used globally without workarounds, like defining them as inline variables in a header file.

Is there a design reason or advantage for this?

Example of using a constexpr in 'contstants.h':

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H
 
// define your own namespace to hold constants
namespace constants
{
    inline constexpr double pi { 3.14159 }; // note: now inline constexpr
    inline constexpr double avogadro { 6.0221413e23 };
    inline constexpr double my_gravity { 9.2 }; // m/s^2 -- gravity is light on this planet
    // ... other related constants
}
#endif
```

Wheras a normal global has external linkage by default:

```
double g_pi { 3.14159 };; // non-constant globals are external by default. So easy!!
```

Comment: `constexpr` variables need to be known at compile time. Linkages occurs after compilation. I presume that with Modules there can be certain improvement but don't expect much as its value needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: `constexpr` implies `inline` - so write `constexpr`. Writing `inline constexpr` is too much noise.

Comment: I guess as a forward declaration would be useless they just decided to disallow it, makes everything simpler

Comment: Why/when would you ever want to forward declare a `constexpr` variable?